# Reusing Components and Maintaining State with Vue

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have created a few linked Vue components that I reuse between multiple projects. Eventually I would like to do it with NPM or a tool like Bit, but right now I am doing it manually.

All of my components are just passing data between themselves using props and emits. This has gotten pretty inefficient as a lot of my components do not sit right next to one another all of the time, so I want to move them over to a more robust solution. Right now I am finding myself having to emit the same data multiple times just to get back up the chain.

Through reading I know that a global event bus can be used to maintain state between components, or Vuex could be used to maintain my overall application state, but how do I factor this into reusable components?

In my head it feels like if I base my components on either option, then I am committing to always using that component with a global event bus or Vuex. And obviously in some projects I may want to switch between using one or the other, depending on the application's complexity.

How do I best approach this? Do I need slightly different components depending on the overall application (this feels like I lose the reuse-ability) or is there something I am not taking into account here?

For one of my applications I have the following simplified component structure:

```
Root Component
    Grid
        Card
            FilterDropdown
            Graph
```

Currently I pass the data into my root component from the API, then pass it down to the Graph component through props at each stage.

On the other side, my FilterDropdown gets a distinct list of one of the data's columns, and provides a dropdown where the user can select a value. This values is then emitted 3 times back up the tree to the root component, where it is used to filter the data via a computed property, that is then passed down again using the same props.

Am I over-complicating things by thinking this needs changing? I can already imaging how I could achieve the same thing, with less overall confusion, by using an event bus or Vuex, but in my head I think I would lose some reuse-ability?

Answer (score 0):

If an app is passing around props to unrelated components or it's becoming tedious to maintain a props/emit chain through multiple descendants, then it's probably a good time to use one of the options you mentioned.  From the Vuex docs:

> passing props can be tedious for deeply nested components, and simply doesn't work for sibling components.

If the architecture isn't that complicated, there's probably no need to switch.  But if there is...

**Vuex Modules**

Since Vuex allows for modules, you can probably eliminate the question of whether it negatively impacts component reusability.  You can think of the component(s) + their dedicated Vuex module(s) as a package.  The Vuex module can encapsulate all of the necessary store functionality without affecting any part of the store of an app that utilizes it.

**Plugins**

You could even create [plugins](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/plugins.html) from these components and use [dynamic module registration](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/modules.html#dynamic-module-registration) to [register their associated Vuex module](https://forum.vuejs.org/t/register-vuex-module-in-vue-plugin/47741/2) in the app's existing store.

You could do something similar with a plugin and event bus.

Instead of thinking of this as committing to a limitation, you can view it as the plugin providing an interface for apps to take advantage of its features.  You could also go with an "all of the above" approach and create a solution for each option.